# Livewire component can't read property sent in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to make new model which is sending the `product_id`. When I try to dump it, it will display the correct data but when I send the request I get error:

```
Attempt to read property "id" on null [On line 155]
```

And my line 155 is:
`'product_id' => $this->product->id,`

At the top of the file I have `public $product;` and I am calling this component as

```
 <livewire:prods.testComponent :product="$product"></livewire:prods.testComponent>
```

And `$product` is provided via `TestComponentController`.

I have also tried to do something like:

```
    public function mount(Product $product){
        $this->product = $product;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you passed ```$product``` to the component when you rendered it and I believe you have a public property in the component called ```$product``` right?. As in ```public $product```. If this is so then ```$this->product``` is already set and you do not need to pass any params to the mount method as well as set it in the mount method because that would reset the parameter you passed.

Comment: Did type hint your Model? like: `public Post $post`

Comment: Can you post the component?